# Reached end of file while parsing error (log attached)

Tags: java, android

I rewrote the code and noticed I had the id wrong so changed it to theListView but I'm still getting errors... :(

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] Categories = {"Abstract", "Android", "Apple", "Animals", "Cartoons", "Celebrities",
            "Girls", "Holidays", "Marvel", "Nature", "Sports", "Vehicles"};

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout, Categories);

    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);

    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new parent.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(parent<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String categoryPicked = "You Selected " +
                    String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, categoryPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
    });
}

@Override
public void (onItemClick(parent<?>parent, View view, int position, long id);
{
    String CategoryPicked = "You selected " + String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, CategoryPicked, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\Brennen\AndroidStudioProjects\Horizon\app\src\main\java\com\example\asus\horizon\MainActivity.java
Error:(48, 57) error: reached end of file while parsing
Error:error: reached end of file while parsing
Information:2 errors

Comment: I posted the log in the question...

Comment: where is my error log/

Comment: unfamiliar what logcat is, I  see event log and gradle

Comment: 00-00 00:00:00.0 0-0/? E/Internal: device 'emulator-5656' not found

Comment: thats what it says when i goto logcat

Answer (score 0):

change

```
String CategoryPicked = "You selected " + String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

to :

```
String CategoryPicked = "You selected " + String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Comment: what exactly is that solving